# Flutter Dynamic Height Horizontal Listivew inside Vertical Listview

Tags: flutter, listview, dynamic, height

I'm facing some difficulties in assembling a layout that is quite common in apps.

I have a ListView.builder, involved in an Expanded inside a Column. For each item, I have a new ListView.builder (horizontal), but it only works if I put a fixed height.

Is there any way to make this horizontal (daughter) list dynamic, with several different sizes, without the need for a fixed height?

```
Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 30, //Only works with this height
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: 2,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      color: index == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
                      child: Text("Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem"),
                    );
                },),
              );
          },),
        )
```

*PS.: I've tried Expanded, Flexible, InstrinctHeight and nothing worked.*

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the design that you are trying to implement?

Comment: Is this really need a list with dynamic height? I can't see where you are trying to put this listview

Comment: @SajadAbdollahi Yes, because the cell is dynamic and the exercise name affects the height of the cell.

Comment: Why just not limiting it to one line? Using `Text(maxLines:1)`

Answer (score 0):

[image: If this is what you want to achieve, I could do it like this]

```
  return Scaffold(
          body: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 30, //Only works with this height
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: 2,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      color: index == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
                      child: Text(
                          "Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem"),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I got it right, but is your answer the same example I gave?

Comment: The answer I gave him was in correspondence of his code, I made some adjustments